# Replace values in dataframe based on column names in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'ref_1': ['A', 'C', 'B'],
        'ref_2': ['B', 'B', 'A'],
        'ref_3': ['C', 'A', 'C']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

# Output
# id  ref_1   ref_2   ref_3
# 1   A       B       C
# 2   C       B       A
# 3   B       A       C

data2 = {'id': [1,2,3],
        'A': [650, 120, 301],
        'B': [120, 134, 133],
        'C': [972, 319, 130]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
# Output
# id  A   B   C
# 1   650 120 972
# 2   120 134 319
# 3   301 133 130
```

I want to replace the values in ref_1, ref_2, and ref_3 with the value under the column name in that cell. So the table should look like this

```
id  ref_1   ref_2   ref_3
1   650     120     972
2   319     134     120
3   133     301     130
```

I can imagine how to do this in a for loop but is there a one-liner?

Comment: actually quite an interesting question. And clearly a vectorised method will be more efficient than a `for loop`, so not sure why it got downvoted ?

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using a `mappper` to [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the values :

```
def f(df):
    return df.set_index("id")

mapper = f(df2).to_dict(orient="index")

out = f(df1).T.replace(mapper).T.reset_index()
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   id  ref_1  ref_2  ref_3
0   1    650    120    972
1   2    319    134    120
2   3    133    301    130
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way:

```
idx,cols = pd.factorize(df.stack())
pd.DataFrame(df2.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df))[:,None],idx.reshape(3,-1)],columns = df.columns)
```

or

```
d = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(df2.columns)}
df2.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df1))[:,None],df1.replace(d).to_numpy()]
```

Output:

```
   ref_1  ref_2  ref_3
0    650    120    972
1    319    134    120
2    133    301    130
```

Answer (score 0):

given a `row` and `column` you can do an efficient extraction (*in its most general form*) like this:

```py
def value_seek(r, c):
    ''' r = row id,   c = columns '''
    result = df1[df1['id']==r][c]       # from the first
    result2 = df2[df1['id']==r][result]  # from the second
    return result2

r = value_seek(1, 'ref_1')
print(r)
```

You would then need to put this into the new dataframe...
for example, using the `.apply()` method.

An alternative complete solution is this:

```py
def vs(row, col):
    column = row[col] 
    return row[column]


df = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
for ref in list(data1.keys())[1:]: df[ref] = df.apply(vs, args=(ref,), axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['A','B','C'])

print(df)
```

which returns this:

```
   id  ref_1  ref_2  ref_3
0   1    650    120    972
1   2    319    134    120
2   3    133    301    130
```